# The selector "app-root" did not match any elements || angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am new to angular 6 and developing admin panel for teachers. i developed the whole admin panel without any problem. After developing admin client gave me a separate html file for login purpose. that's where the whole problem started. So i decided to do it by routing. I created layout for admin panel as well as the login page. But now i am getting ** "app-root" selector did not match** error.

Below is my appComponent typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {ToastrService} from './services/toastr.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
  providers:[ToastrService]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  }
```

This is my index.html

```
<app-root>loading....</app-root>
```

below is th errror i am getting

```
the selector "app-root" did not match any elements
at DefaultDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.js:1073)
at BaseAnimationRenderer.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (animations.js:229)
at DebugRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (core.js:20837)
at createElement (core.js:17499)
at createViewNodes (core.js:19737)
at createRootView (core.js:19690)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20722)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:20208)
at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:18029)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:7812)
```

What i am missing. Any one please help.

Comment: have you added this component in app.module.ts?

Comment: either you didn't add component into declaration inside of app-module.ts or you didn't add bootstraping component.

Comment: yeah i have check the suggestion and everything is fine.

Comment: can you post also the app module?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve a similar problem by adding a body tag to my index.html that encloses the app-root tag as follows:

```
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Comment: same issue. This solution worked!  Is this a Angular 7 thing?