# Angular Elements - Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement'

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I have been trying to get an Angular elements component working, as I was considering using them in an upcoming project.

I have followed a number of tutorials (all very similar), and just cannot get them working. One of the tutorials is [this one](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-elements-web-components/).

I have the following package.json for the Elements project

```
        {
      "name": "angular-webcomponents-demo",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "build:elements": "ng build --prod --output-hashing none && node build-script.js"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/elements": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
        "document-register-element": "^1.7.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
        "concat": "^1.0.3",
        "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~3.2.2"
      }
    }
```

I built using `npm un build:elements` as instructed, and then attempted to host in the simplest html I could

ie

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="analytics-counter.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <analytics-counter></analytics-counter>
</body>
</html>
```

Initially I was getting errors similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441437/the-selector-app-root-did-not-match-any-elements-angular-6) (except mine mentioned `custom-root` rather than `app-root'.

I have removed the component from the bootstrap, so I now have the following in my `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AnalyticsCounterComponent } from './analytics-counter/analytics-counter.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AnalyticsCounterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    AnalyticsCounterComponent
  ],
  providers: []  
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {     
  }
  ngDoBootstrap() {    
    const el = createCustomElement(AnalyticsCounterComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('analytics-counter', el);
  }
}
```

I removed the `<custom-root>` from the index.html as well as I saw suggeted elswhere

The error I am now getting is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
        at t [as constructor] (analytics-counter.js:4)
        at new t (analytics-counter.js:4)
        at CustomElementRegistry.e.<computed> [as define] (analytics-counter.js:2)
        at new e (analytics-counter.js:4)
        at analytics-counter.js:4
        at Mo (analytics-counter.js:4)
        at analytics-counter.js:4
        at new e (analytics-counter.js:4)
        at Object.ti [as createNgModuleRef] (analytics-counter.js:4)
        at t.create (analytics-counter.js:4)
```

The tutorials and explanations all look pretty straight forward, yet I cannot get the most basic example working.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error. The problem comes from `build-script.js`. You will have to modify it and make sure it's compiling only `es2015.js` files instead of `es5.js`. ES5 has some trouble working with native Custom Elements, therefore you will have to use ES2015.

So it will look something like this:

```
const files = [
  './dist/CustomElements/runtime-es2015.js',
  './dist/CustomElements/polyfills-es2015.js',
  './dist/CustomElements/main-es2015.js'
];
```

Also feel free to check my working demo repository of Angular Elements - [Angular Custom Elements](https://github.com/dinohorvat/angular-custom-elements). The output is already in `elements/` folder so you can just run the `index.html` there to test it. I was able to reproduce the error by replacing es2015 to es5 in a build script on this exact project.

Comment: thankyou very much! Changing `"target": "es2015"` in my tsconfig.json' gets me an element which will work in Chrome, which is what I at least initially wanted to do. Now the next step is to go back to `es5` and look at the various polyfills, as I (at least initially) will need this to work in (horrid) IE11 (until we finish converting all the old Silverlight to Angular) - but that is all for a different posts - where I know I will run into problems)

Comment: I added a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586274/angular-elements-polyfills-to-use-in-ie11-and-edge-problems)